# What does luminance have to do with the blackbody node?

Tags: node-editor, osl

I have noticed that the blackbody node has a 'scale by luminance' in its OSL code.

This is the code:

```js
/* Scale by luminance */
    float l = luminance(rgb);
    if (l != 0.0)
        rgb /= l;
    Color = rgb;
```

What does luminance have to do with the blackbody node?

Comment: Can you give a source/link for that code? The blackbody code that I'm finding in the Cycles kernel doesn't say anything about luminance.

Comment: @ScottMilner I am not sure if the source code is available on Github or anywhere else. I downloaded it from blender.org. You can find the code in intern/cycles/kernel/shaders

Comment: Actually >We don't want lights that are lit at varying temperatures to be perceived as brighter or darker than the others Isn't actually this exactly what you want? Warmer lights *should* be brighter.. Or at least is there a way of turning this on? I am gonna have to learn to code to create what I want I think

Comment: @AndrewBrown Color temperature does not directly correspond to the heat of the light source emitting it. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature), color temperature is `temperature of an ideal black-body radiator that radiates light of a color comparable to that of the light source`. For example, the sky has a color temperature of **15000K+**, but definitely isn't that hot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what Luminance means:

> Luminance...is a measure to describe the perceived brightness of a color.
>
> [Source](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-luminance-2233.htm)

Since luminance is the *perceived* brightness, not all hues with the same saturation will have the same luminance. The website linked above has a useful image:

[image]

From the image above, we can see that even though all of the colors have 100% saturation, their luminance varies a lot. Yellow light (2,800 **K**) has a luminance of 94%, while blue light (10,000 **K**) only has a luminance of 57%.

This becomes a problem with the **Blackbody** node, since its usual purpose is to provide color for **Emission** shaders and lamps. We don't want lights that are lit at varying temperatures to be perceived as brighter or darker than the others. We'd rather control this on our own with the **Emission** node.

All of the colors coming from the **Blackbody** node are divided by their own luminance as a kind of **normalization**, so that they all have the *same perceived brightness*.